# The next section is below previous section

Tags: bootstrap-5

I make card wrap by container

here is my code
i make new section next to this section.. but next section is below this section..
what makes next section is below previous section, btw i am using bootstrap 5

```
   <div class="container-fluid room">
      <h2 class="room-section-title text-center"> Our Rooms</h2>
      <div class="container d-flex justify-content-evenly align-items-center flex-md-column flex-lg-row flex-column ">
         <div class="card mx-3">
            <img src="/assets/images/room/Deluxe.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
               <h5 class="card-title">Superior Room</h5>
               <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
               </p>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a class="text-primary text-decoration-none" href="#">Room detail</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card mx-3">
            <img src="/assets/images/room/Deluxe.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
               <h5 class="card-title">Deluxe Room</h5>
               <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
               </p>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a class="text-primary text-decoration-none" href="#">Room detail</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="card mx-3">
            <img src="/assets/images/room/Deluxe.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
               <h5 class="card-title">Suite Room</h5>
               <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
               </p>
               <div class="btn">
                  <a class="text-primary text-decoration-none" href="#">Room detail</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the whole file. Then only we can answer it.